# Combine JWT authentication and authorizeRequests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am building a spring boot API for security I use JWT token, I also developed a web version for authentication I use authorizeRequests.

I want to combine the two authentication modes so that the filter is used for all URLs that start with **/api/**** and requestMatchers are applied for the rest.

This works perfectly for the webClient application:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login");
```

And it works correctly for the API :

```
http.csrf().disable()
            .addFilterAfter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/signin").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

""

Can you please help to conbine the two codes

Thank you in advance

Comment: you do know that spring security already has a built in jwtfilter that you can use and customize so you dont have to write one yourself?

Comment: you can get reference from below medium link having Project in Github for the same 

https://medium.com/@igor.bonny/multiple-spring-boot-security-configuration-c876f1b6061e

Comment: I followed the doc you shared @Divya and it works perfectly for me, thank you SO much. https://medium.com/@igor.bonny/multiple-spring-boot-security-configuration-c876f1b6061e

Answer (score 0):

We can configure [multiple `HttpSecurity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity) instances just as we can have multiple `http` blocks. The key is to extend the `WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter` multiple times.

Comment: Thanks a LOT Alex for your answer, now I want to be able to access /api/signin without authentication, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, just to add [there is a component-based way](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.7.0-M2/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity) to configure Spring Security since version 5.5

Answer (score 0):

I used multiple HttpSecurity and it works perfectely thank you for you help

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
@Configuration
public static class RestConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/api/**")
            .cors()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable() // we don't need CSRF because our token is invulnerable
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/signin").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/signup").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/signin").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}


    
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login");
    }
}
```